# How to select multiple counts from the same column in hive

Tags: hive

I have the following table in hive :

userid   productid   action

```
 1      101    Browse
 2      102   Clicked
 3      103 AddToCart
 4      104 Purchase
 5      105   LogOut
 6      106   Browse
 7      107   Browse
 8      108   Browse
 9      109  Clicked
10      110  Clicked
11      111  Clicked
12      112  Clicked
13      101   Browse
14      101   Browse
15      101   Browse
16      101   Browse
17      102  Clicked
18      103 AddToCart
19      102  Clicked
20      103 AddToCart
```

Now in my output i want productid and count of those actions which are Browse or Clicked.

**

- Output :

**

```
productid browseCount clickCount

  101         5         1
  102      null         4
  106         1      null
  107         1      null
  108         1      null
  109      null         1
  110      null         1
  111      null         1
  112      null         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with conditional sum, e.g.,

```
select
productid,
  sum(if(action = 'Browse', 1, 0)) as BrowseCount,
  sum(if(action = 'Clicked', 1, 0)) as ClickedCount
from table
group by productid
```

Comment: i want to select top 5 product id ?

Comment: "top 5" based on what criterion? what count?

Comment: find top 5 most viewed products. A product is considered as viewed if the action contains “Browse or Clicked”.  Output should contain count of “Browse” and count of “Click” separately

Comment: you have two columns with counts. What column you need to sort to extract top 5 rows? it's not clear from you question/